Java 22 build failed: ofVirtual() is unknown
I can not comile a project:
grim@main:~/workspace/hl-editor$ mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< hl:hl-editor >----------------------------
[INFO] Building hl-editor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ hl-editor ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ hl-editor ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ hl-editor ---
[INFO] Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
[INFO] Compiling 56 source files with javac [debug parameters release 17] to target/classes
[INFO] /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/src/main/java/hl/level/LevelUIComponentPositioner.java: /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/src/main/java/hl/level/LevelUIComponentPositioner.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/src/main/java/hl/level/LevelUIComponentPositioner.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/src/main/java/hl/Editor.java:[43,65] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method ofVirtual()
  location: class java.lang.Thread
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.787 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-25T10:09:54+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project hl-editor: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/grim/workspace/hl-editor/src/main/java/hl/Editor.java:[43,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method ofVirtual()
[ERROR]   location: class java.lang.Thread
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
grim@main:~/workspace/hl-editor$ 

The ofVirtual-method is:
@Bean
public ExecutorService es() {
    return Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(Thread.ofVirtual().factory());
}

My java-home is:
grim@main:~/workspace/hl-editor$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/grim/graalvm-jdk-22+36.1
grim@main:~/workspace/hl-editor$ 

What am I doing wrong?

"Compiling 56 source files with javac [debug parameters release 17]"
